# Identical Notebook can't import module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two identical Jupyter Notebooks in two different folders.  If I fire up jupyter notebooks and open one of the notebooks, and run the cell with:

```
import example_name
```

it loads just fine.

If I open the identical notebook in the other folder and try running the same:

```
import example_name
```

I get error message:

```
ImportError: No module named example_name
```

What could explain this and how do I track down the filepath to 'example_name' in the notebook where it loads fine?

Comment: Well, is `example_name.py` in the other folder as too?

Comment: In the one where it loads, do a `print (example_name.__file__)` to see the full pathname to the module.  This should tell you what's missing from the other one.

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you for getting back to me.  When I run print(example_name._file_) in the notebook where it loads,  I get an error message "NameError: name 'example_name' is not defined".

Comment: But you said the import worked.  The name __can't__ be undefined.  Are you using the actual module name?  (I assume it isn't really named `example_name`.)

Comment: @PeterWood  The issue was when I import it I alias it.  So import example_name as en.  So when I ran print(en._file_) I got "/home/user_name/other-library/example_name.py".  The problem I have now is when I run "cd ~" in my terminal I don't see a "other-library" in the directory even when I show the hidden files.  Could it be that the "other-library" folder got deleted and since I haven't restarted the kernel it's still working when I run the cell with the import example_name as en line in it?

Comment: @modLmakur read about [ask] particularly how to create a [mcve],

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import a module named `example_name` from the directory in which the notebook resides `./` - the module - a file called `example_name.py` - exists in one of the directories but not the other.

The issue is related python `sys.path` which tells the python interpreter where to load python modules from, you can print this list of directories and you should see an entry for `.` - which is the current directory and a bunch of other directories.

You can either copy the `example_name.py` file along with the notebook or add the directory path of `example_name.py` to `sys.path` using `sys.path.append('/some/path')`.

To do this correctly you would actually have a directory on your computer which contains all the scripts you need in your notebooks, and add that directory path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. That way the directory will always be added to `sys.path`.